# How to create separate columns from the value of from the table

Tags: sql

I create separate columns from the value of field of `NAME` using `CASE`. But the result has too many rows:

| NAME | VALUES |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | 2023-10-10T00:00:00 |
| NO | ABC2134832312 |
| MILEAGE | 6500 |
| CLASS | B |
| INITIAL | A |

Here the query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN hdr_id = 7 THEN value END AS Date,
    CASE WHEN hdr_id = 8 THEN value END AS No, 
    CASE WHEN hdr_id = 20 THEN value END AS mileage, 
    CASE WHEN hdr_id = 18 THEN value END AS CLASS, 
    CASE WHEN hdr_id = 19 THEN value END AS INITIAL 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    hdr_id IN (7, 8, 18, 19, 20) AND id = 13
```

This is the current result:

| ID | DATE | NO | MILEAGE | CLASS | INITIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2023-10-10T00:00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| 13 |  | ABC2134832312 |  |  |  |
| 13 |  |  | 6500 |  |  |
| 13 |  |  |  | B |  |
| 13 |  |  |  |  | A |

This is the expected result:

| ID | DATE | NO | MILEAGE | CLASS | INITIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2023/10/10 | ABC2134832312 | 6500 | B | A |

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Well - how are we supposed to help, if you don't ***SHOW US*** that SQL that you used!

Comment: Do I detect an EAV table?

Comment: Hi @marc_s here the script i have
Select id   
, case when hdr_id = 7 then  value end as Date
, case when hdr_id = 8 then  value end as No
, case when hdr_id = 20 then value end as mileage
, case when hdr_id = 18 then value end as CLASS
, case when hdr_id = 19 then value end as INITIAL
FROM table
WHERE hdr_id in (7,8,20,18,19)
AND id = 13

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Hi @marc_s its my first time to use this stackoverflow i send only a link of script image cause every time i add the script i received error cant proceed.

Comment: Did you try to add MIN or MAX around the case expressions? What should the first table in your question show? This is obviously not your sample input data because it doesn't have a column named "hdr_id ".

Comment: Add in each column case "max( CASE WHEN hdr_id = 7 THEN value END) Name"

Comment: Hi @CarlosCocom thank you for this its working this concern is solve using MAX Thank you

Comment: Than you all also marc_s and Jonas Metzler